# How to restart boot Windows 7 after upgrading to a SSD on SONY VAIO with recovery discs?

Tags: windows-7, sony-vaio

The original HDD on my **Sony VAIO** still works, but has a damaged sector 0 and I was constantly prompted to replace the HDD because of the imminent failure.

I created recovery discs as instructed, used a USB external HDD for complete back up (including Windows image back up).

After installing the SSHD and using recovery discs to upload Windows and boot, I am getting the Windows welcome screen. Right after that, I'm getting the following message:

> Windows couldn't complete the installation.
>   To install Windows on this computer, restart the installation.

I have tried repeating the process many times all kinds of different ways and I still receive the same message.

Also, when I tried to change to partitioning as the other option offered, I get the message:

> Windows Setup could not configure Windows to run on this computer's hardware.

All troubleshooting for hardware and *PCU* came out solid. I tried to load the image back up from the external drive, but can't load the driver. The computer doesn't see it. Does anyone have a clue or has encountered something similar?

Answer (score 0):

- Put in the SSD and start the computer.
- Tap F8 to get the black and white "Advanced Boot Options" screen.
- Use the arrows to select "Repair your computer" and tap Enter
- The colorful Microsoft "System Recovery Options" screen should appear.

From here you have several options. You may want to go into a Command Prompt and look at the repair Master Boot Record commands (bootrec). There are some examples here: http://www.thewindowsclub.com/repair-master-boot-record-mbr-windows

Answer (score 0):

Recovery discs created with software pre-installed on your computer are typically hardware specific. By this I mean they have all the drivers pre-installed including storage drivers. Even if your computer was using a hard drive supported by the default Windows driver which it most likely was, my understanding is that Windows uses different drivers for ssds and hard drives. It also will normally enable TRIM. Since it's not an installation disc, it's a restore disc it doesn't detect and re-configure Windows for use with new hardware, it just dumps the image on the disk from a series of wim files, so the ssd can't be used. I have the same problem with my Toshiba so I feel for your predicament.